# Displaying multiple routes with Google Maps JS v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a dynamic number of routes onto a single map. Of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137712/handling-multiple-routes-with-waypoints-in-google-maps-v3) I've found on SO, they all seem to hard code the number of points instead of dynamically processing them.

## My Solution

In this example, I'm handling multiple shipments and then trying to plot the route on the Google Maps with DirectionsService. This means -

- Looping over each shipment
- Grabbing the startPoint & endPoint
- Making the request
- Processing the response

## Code

The solution I've come up with is -

```
function initMap(shipments) {
  var shipments = shipments;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom:4
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Plot Points
  if (shipments.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < shipments.length; i++) {
          var startPoint = {};
          var endPoint = {};
          // Each Shipment
          for (z = 0; z < shipments[i]['points'].length; z++) {
            var point  = shipments[i]['points'][z]
            var lat = point['point'][0]
            var lng = point['point'][1]
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
              map: map,
              label: point['name'],
              icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+ point['color'] +'.png',
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            if (marker.label == 'start') {
              startPoint = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            }
            if (marker.label == 'destination') {
              endPoint = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            }
          }
          var request = {
            origin: startPoint,
            destination: endPoint,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          };
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map,
            suppressMarkers: true
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              // Display the route on the map.
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          });
          // map.fitBounds(bounds);
      };
  }
}
```

## Problem

The problem is that this only plots the last shipment instead of plotting and rendering each. Where am I not processing the response properly? The data is going through correctly, but it is rendering the following -

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close! You will need to create a `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` per route. Keep in mind you will also need to keep track of these renders for removal, clean up, etc. Try something like this:

```
function initMap(shipments) {
  var shipments = shipments;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom:4
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Plot Points
  if (shipments.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < shipments.length; i++) {
          var startPoint = {};
          var endPoint = {};
          // Each Shipment
          for (z = 0; z < shipments[i]['points'].length; z++) {
            var point  = shipments[i]['points'][z]
            var lat = point['point'][0]
            var lng = point['point'][1]
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
              map: map,
              label: point['name'],
              icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+ point['color'] +'.png',
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            if (marker.label == 'start') {
              startPoint = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            }
            if (marker.label == 'destination') {
              endPoint = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            }
          }
          var request = {
            origin: startPoint,
            destination: endPoint,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          };

          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
              // Display the route on the map.
              console.log(response)
              renderDirections(response, map);
            }
          });
          // map.fitBounds(bounds);
      };
  }
}

function renderDirections(result, map) { 
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  }); 
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map); 
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result); 
}
```

Comment: In my research I found this answer on another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936742/5790134 he divides each section in to more readable functions if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solution unfortunately didn't work - although I think you are pointing in the right direction.

Comment: None but still drawing the one route

Comment: Silly question, but can you confirm `shipments` does have multiple routes?

Comment: Yes, if you look in the image, the green points are starts and red are ends. 2 different routes going in two different directions.

Comment: Right, I see. I think this is likely due to  `directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);` being asynchronous and we're resetting the start and stop points. Let's move those into the for loop as well. Updating answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165853/discussion-between-emile-and-phillip-thomas).